# How to open web links in external browser like Chrome from Reddit?

Tags: chrome-for-android, hyperlinks

I have a habit of using an external browser for web links to generally read articles, but wherever I click on any link it opens up in the internal browser which prevents me from using Reddit otherwise at the same time in my Android smartphone. How do I open web links from Reddit in an external browser like Google Chrome in my Android smartphone?

P.S. I am using official Reddit app for Android. Reddit for Android has its own browser to load web links. Is there any way to get rid of that and open web links in any external browser like Chrome?

Comment: Which app are you using to view Reddit? For instance, I use BaconReader, and it has a setting that specifies whether to use the internal or external browser.

Comment: I am using the official Reddit app.

Comment: If you find the default browser in Settings -> Apps and tap on it, under **App info** you'll see the heading **Open by default**: tap on it and then press **CLEAR DEFAULTS**. Now in all apps you'll be prompted for which browser to use, with the default browser offering the choices of USE ONCE or USE ALWAYS, which will remove the prompt again on future links.

Comment: Your method worked, @AFH but it turn out the case is different. Reddit for Android has its own browse to load web links. Is there any way to get rid of that and open web links in any external browser like Chrome, as I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed all apps would be similar. I have no experience of Reddit.

Comment: No problem, I think there is no option for such, instead of finding something in Reddit settings or using a totally third party app.